# Convert range to integer

Tags: vba, excel

In the following code, `CalendarMonths` is a range containing month names. `endDate` is also a range.

I need to translate those names into month numbers, however the following method using `Month` function returns "type mismatch" error (even if I skip `CInt`):

```
For Each CalendarMonth In CalendarMonths
            If CInt(Month(CalendarMonth)) = CInt(Month(endDate)) Then
```

Comment: THe Month function expects an input of type Date, not a string.

Comment: is `EndDate` and actual date? or is it a string also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a month as `String` and want to convert to `Long`:

```
Sub skjdffhs()
    Dim s As String, n As Long
    s = "January"
    n = Month(CDate("1 " & s & " 2000"))
    MsgBox n
End Sub
```

*(this is for the US locale)*

Comment: You can do without the year so it defaults to the current year.  `CDate("1 " & s)`  Either way gives the same result though. :)